# Open file mode string w+

Tags: io, lua

I know what `io.open(file, "w")` does, it indicates writting. However I have encountered `io.open(file, "w+")` and can't find what "w+" does?

Comment: I have the same question - why does lua have three modes of writing: "Write", "Append" and "Write+"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the reference manual [io.open](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-io.open)

> The `mode` string can be any of the following:
>
> - "r": read mode (the default);
> - "w": write mode;
> - "a": append mode;
> - "r+": update mode, all previous data is preserved;
> - **"w+": update mode, all previous data is erased;**
> - "a+": append update mode, previous data is preserved, writing is only allowed at the end of file.

*update mode* here means, both input and output may be performed on the
associated file.

Comment: This does not answer the question - which I think is a reasonable one. In most languages there are two variations of writing to a file - "append" puts extra stuff on the end of an existing file, and "write" blanks the existing file content and starts writing from byte number 0. I read this very section of the manual and turned here for clarification.

Comment: @NULLpointer Most languages, really? These modes are all available in at least C / Python / Ruby / Lua ..., and some other languages support all of these modes implicitly in some encapsulated way, which is the case for C++ / Java.

Comment: That's better! Your edit added the key information that was missing - both input and output can be performed with w+

Answer (score 7):

io.open just uses fopen of C. you could check the [manual of fopen in C](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fopen.html).

- w: Truncate  file to zero length or create text file for writing. 
  The stream is positioned at the beginning of the file.
- w+: the same as w, besides the handle returned could be used for
  reading.

Comment: Thanks a ton, this is the best explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I tested this in Lua 5.1 running on OpenWRT and found

```
file=io.open("/usr/share/result","w")
```

was the same as

```
file=io.open("/usr/share/result","w+")
```

Both actions erased the current content of the file and re-wrote it.

When I tried

```
file=io.open("/usr/share/result","a")
```

The file was appended to - it got longer and longer each time my code ran.

So I don't think there is a difference.

Comment: This answer is wrong. The difference between **write mode** and **update mode** is: with `"w"` mode, you can only output to the file, while with `"w+"` mode, both input and output can be performed.

Comment: As a side note, do you really think the language designer (not just Lua, but also C / Python / Ruby, etc) would keep both if `"w"` and `"w+"` were really the same?